# Using docker with hypervisor instead of wsl2

Tags: docker, hyper-v, wsl-2, hypervisor, hyper-virtualization

Before I hear about wsl, I was using virtualbox and some other software to use linux. But wsl was amazing. Instead of allocating mamory wsl uses dynamic allocation that was really useful. When I heard about wsl2 in docker I was really happy. But nothing went as expected. A process named  **vmmem** starts with wsl2 backend and uses almost 2gbs of ram. Even if I use the hyper-v backed I would not allocate that much memory. Even with **wsl2 ubuntu** or **wsl2 kali** the same process starts but does not allocate that memory. I searched on youtube, Quora, Google and everything I could not get any solutions.

I wanted to switch back to hyper-v backend or wanted to get rid of the **vmmem** process, So please help me

Thanks to everyone who read this kindly and special thanks to the one who is going to solve my problem

> *I can give you any additional information if you want*

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, there is a checkbox in the Docker settings (right click Docker icon > Settings > General) labelled "Use the WSL 2 based engine" which will do what you are looking for.

However, if you want to give WSL another go, you can limit the amount of memory that WSL can allocate.

If you create a file in your `%userprofile%`, called `.wslconfig` and give it the contents:

```
[wsl2]
memory=1GB
```

However, there is an [ongoing issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4166) with WSL2 and Docker that appears to indicate a memory leak. Limiting the memory in this way may cause undesirable side effects.

Comment: It's 1 year later and I'm installing docker. On my screen I see "Use WSL2 instead of Hyper-V (recommended)"... since that memory issue is still open, I feel that this may not be recommended.